# Absolute frequency shift of red shift 11.9

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion, redshift

According to a [2012 article about the Hubble Telescope](https://www.spacetelescope.org/news/heic1219/), the Hubble found the most distant galaxy at a red shift of "11.9". What does this mean in terms of THz frequency? For example, I know that the frequency of normal visible light ranges from 400 to 800 terahertz. How many terahertz is 11.9?

Comment: Have you looked up how redshift is defined?  Have you attempted to calculate what effect this has on visible wavelengths?  Please note the site policy on homework and exercises such as this calculation : http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/

Comment: it's a simple formula. Choose a frequency and apply ... Search for redshift on wiki

Comment: @igael If I found the problem to be simple I would not have asked the question.

Comment: @TylerDurden: it's very basic, you must search a little ... [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift) says for frequencies that $(1 + z) = \frac{a_{\mathrm{then}}}{a_{\mathrm{now}}}$ , 
then $a_{\mathrm{now}} = \frac {a_{\mathrm{then}}} {( 1 + z )}$ , and for 400 tHz & z = 11.9 , $a_{\mathrm{now}} = \frac{400}{( 1 + 11.9 )} tHz$. ( as well stated by JohnRennie )

Answer (score 2):

Suppose light is emitted from a distant galaxy with a frequency $f_0$, and when we receive the light its frequency has decreased to $f$. We can define a ratio:

$$ R = \frac{f_0}{f} $$

So if no red shift has occurred $f=f_0$ and $R=1$. If the light has been redshifted $f \lt f_0$ and $R \gt 1$. However it's nice to have a measure that is zero for no red shift, so we define the red shift parameter $z$ by:

$$ z = R - 1 $$

or:

$$ z= \frac{f_0}{f} - 1 \tag{1} $$

This way $z=0$ means no red shift and as the red shift gets bigger $z$ gets bigger.

Now back to your question. When the article says the red shift is $11.9$ it means $z=11.9$. If we take equation (1) and rearrange it we get:

$$ f = f_0 \frac{1}{1+z} $$

So in this case the frequency of the light we receive is $f=f_0/12.9$ or around 50THz, which is a wavelength of around 6 microns.